django %(class)s does not get correctly replaced when used in m2m relationship to self in abstract model
Django docs advise to set related_name and related_query_name using class/app name placeholders %(class)s and %(app_label)s.
I am finding that in an abstract model with a many-to-many field to itself, these labels are not replaced correctly. Is this because they are unnecessary in a "self" many-to-many relationship?
class GeographicalArea(models.Model):
    successors = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self",
        symmetrical=False,
        blank=True,
        related_name="%(class)s_predecessors",
        related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_predecessor",
        help_text="Successors of area if changed.",
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Country(GeographicalArea):
    name = models.CharField(
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
    )


...generates a migration script where related_name='%(class)s_predecessors' and related_query_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_predecessor' instead of related_name='country_predecessors' and related_query_name='myapp_country_predecessor' as I expected.

labels in migrations are not correct but they don't matter at all, related_name is instantiated on class level and would be set correctly to country_predecessors

The migrations don't display the final names, but it will work anyway.
Run the migrations, related_name and related_query_name will be as expected:
from my_app.models import Country
Country._meta.get_field("successors").remote_field.related_query_name
>>> 'my_app_country_predecessors'


Thank you. I was reading the migration as the final name of the fields.

I am not clear on why the class name is required in the many-to-many relationship field. Using only related_name='predecessors' creates a table called myapp_country_successors with from_country_id and to_country_id fields. Accessing the instances can be done with country.successors or country.predecessors. When would this become an issue?

Answering my own comment: I believe this would not be an issue with "self", only when the many-to-many field refers to a 3rd class. An example would be a Person abstract model from which both Studend and Teacher inherit. If Person has a schools many-to-many field with related_name people, then school.people would not resolve.
